# Magento Custom Module Creation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to build a custom interface (See PSD) for the user to add social urls and display an icon if not empty. I did something similar in WP but no idea how to do it in Magento. I was wondering if someone can help or point to a tutorial. Thanks a lot[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can read this series by Alan Storm:

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

"Magento For PHP MVC Developers"